# Explanation for dual slope DVM voltage measurement

Tags: voltmeter

I want to design a dual slope integral digital voltmeter. After reading about how it works, I have a question about its voltage measurement.

[image]

How can we say that our required voltage is the count of t2 time period as we have taken t1 time period as the time to charge the capacitor using input voltage (the voltage we measure.)

Comment: @datenheim I don't know. Maybe it made more sense prior to some edit or was meant for another question/answer. Deleting...

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor is charged from zero volts initial condition to an unknown voltage of

\$-t_1 \frac{V_{IN}}{RC} \$

(assuming Vin constant, otherwise it's the integral wrt time over that period).

t1 ends when the counter rolls over to zero and toggles the flip-flop. So the count during the de-integration phase (t2) starts with the counter at 0 and ends when the voltage at the capacitor e0 crosses zero when the counter stops counting (some control logic is missing here for continuous conversions).

The time it takes to get to 0 is proportional to Vin, and will be equal to the counter rollover time if Vin = -Vref, assuming C, R and the clock are *stable*.

So if the reference is 1 volt and the counter is 3 BCD digits, the counter will hold the measured voltage in millivolts after the comparator gates the clock off.

A full dual-slope converter typically has a bit more control logic for starting the conversion at 0 (eg. auto-zero) and to change the reference polarity if the input signal is negative rather than positive.

Comment: my doubt is if the integrator's capacitor gets charged for the input voltage then why don't you consider that time interval and count it and make it as the measured voltage,( let us take a big capacitor and the time required to get charged for the input given voltage can be counted) What do you say for this?

Comment: So, to do that, you need to have some threshold to charge to, and you need to know what the exact RC time constant is. And I think you would need to do some math - i.e. you need precision components and a microcontroller. With a dual slope ADC, the precise RC time constant is irrelevant as it affects both the charging and discharging equally and as such cancels out. All you need is a precise voltage reference, stable clock, and the ability to display the final counter value.

Answer (score 1):

For reference. Made with FREE [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).

Here is a [working schematic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xeu58hdf8iu7om/DOUBLE%20RAMPE%20031.CIR?dl=0) and simulation for the dual-slope voltmeter.
Please note that 2 references are used (positive/negative slopes).

It shows the "calculus" through the triangles of the slopes (where crossing the line 0 V).

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 3 results are 1152, 2225, and 3330 for voltages input of 2 V, 0 V, and -2 V.
The real answer to the count is the "difference" (+ sign) from 2225.