# Quad slope ADC and dual slope ADC

Tags: adc, power-electronics, dac

I know that the output of a dual slope ADC doesn't depend upon the value of the resistor and capacitor used, so its output is accurate. How does a quad slope ADC work? How is the output of a quad slope ADC more accurate than a dual slope ADC?

Comment: See my functional Dual-slope circuit (no errors corrected) 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393526/explanation-for-dual-slope-dvm-voltage-measurement/652625#652625  . You can add a third slope for fast down slope, and a fourth slope for recovering offset errors ...

Answer (score 6):

Integrating ADCs have errors associated with offset voltages and bias currents.  Quad-slope ADCs, in addition to looking at the input voltage, also look at zero input and full scale input to correct those errors.

See Analog Devices document MT-27 for a review: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-027.pdf

Comment: Very interesting references in that reference, learnt a lot about triple- and quad-slope conversion